# Reportviewer memory leak C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, reportviewer

When printing the receipt through the reportviewer memory leakage is arising. Even though I have tried other solutions mentioned non of it didn't give me any positive outcome.
I have run the garbage collector but still did not get any outcome properly. Please give me a proper solution to sort out the matter.

```
    static string myconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconn);
    readonly SalesF sf;
    public RecieptForm(SalesF frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.sf = frm;

    }

    private void RecieptForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
    public void LoadReceipt(string cashTendered, string cashBalance)
    {
        ReportDataSource receiptds;
        try
        {
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Reports\CashPaymentReciept.rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            DataSet1 dc = new DataSet1();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            string query = "select c.id,c.transno,c.productid,c.price,c.quantity,c.total,c.transactiondate,p.description from tbl_cart as c inner join product as p on p.productID=c.productid where transno like '" + sf.lblInvoiceNumber.Text + "'";
            conn.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            sda.Fill(dc.Tables["dtSold"]);

            sda.Dispose();
            dc.Dispose();

            ReportParameter cartTotal = new ReportParameter("cartTotal", sf.lblAmount.Text);
            ReportParameter cashTend = new ReportParameter("cashTendered", cashTendered);
            ReportParameter cashBal = new ReportParameter("cashBalance", cashBalance);
            ReportParameter storeName = new ReportParameter("storeName", store.ToUpper());
            ReportParameter cashier = new ReportParameter("cashier", "Cashier: " + sf.lblName.Text);



            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(cartTotal);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(cashTend);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(cashBal);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(storeName);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(cashier);
            receiptds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dc.Tables["dtSold"]);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(receiptds);                

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.PrintToPrinter();
          
        

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sf.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(reportViewer1);
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you believe you actually have a memory leak? Maybe you simple have so much memory that there is no need to free it right after you're done with the objects?

Comment: The Microsoft ReportViewer has a known memory-leak that has been on-going for years. If you take a look at the following link "Randy Lee" came up with some code to address the problem of "event-handlers" not being released resulting in a memory leak. He has both C# and VB code. Not sure if this will help you or not:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/d21f8b56-3123-4aff-bf84-9cce727bc2ce/possible-memory-leak-with-reportviewerrefreshreport?forum=vsreportcontrols

Comment: Just bumping this. I'm seeing the same issue still using the newest version from NuGet. I'm using an object pool of LocalReport and reusing the instances without disposing them. I'm running the same reports. Seems to be leaking unmanaged memory also. The LocalReport seems to have a growing set of HashSet references being held internally. After a few hundred runs the HashSet is around 80mb. This just grows and grows along with other things.